# Replacing values in json file with jq

Tags: json, bash, sh, jq

I have a JSON file like

```
{
    "Changes": [{
        "Action": "UPSERT",
        "ResourceRecordSet": {
            "Name": "RESOURCE_NAME",
            "Type": "A",
            "TTL": 60,
            "ResourceRecords": [{
                "Value": "RESOURCE_HOSTS"
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

where I need to replace `.Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.Name` and `.Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords[]` dynamically.

So, I wrote a script to replace required values with `jq`.

```
#!/bin/bash -xe

RESOURCE_NAME="example.com"
RESOURCE_HOSTS="1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,"

cat resource-changes.json | \
jq '.Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.Name=env.RESOURCE_NAME' | \
jq 'del(.Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords[])' \
> resource-changes.$$.json && \
mv resource-changes.$$.json resource-changes.json

for host in $(echo "$RESOURCE_HOSTS" | tr "," "\n"); do
  cat resource-changes.json | \
  jq --arg theHost $host '.Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords |= (. + [{"Value":$theHost}])' \
  > resource-changes.$$.json
  mv resource-changes.$$.json resource-changes.json
done

jq '.' resource-changes.json
```

Which works fine and I can get required replacements. Though the script looks quite long and complicated IMO. Also, I do not really like joggling with temporary files. I'm looking for a way to simplify the script. Appreciate any comments!

Comment: It would be great to add a `jq` tag. Do not have enough power for it..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Accessing environment variables in `jq`

This doesn't really work as it is...:

> ```
> RESOURCE_NAME="example.com"
> # ...
>
> cat resource-changes.json | \
> jq '.Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.Name=env.RESOURCE_NAME' | \
> # ...
> ```

`jq` cannot access `RESOURCE_NAME` if it's not exported.
The fix is simple:

```
export RESOURCE_NAME="example.com"
```

#### Iterating over a list of values

This is a very hacky way to iterate over a list of hosts:

> ```
> RESOURCE_HOSTS="1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,"
>
> # ...
>
> for host in $(echo "$RESOURCE_HOSTS" | tr "," "\n"); do
> ```

If the host names will never contain space,
you could use a simple space-separated string:

```
RESOURCE_HOSTS="1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2"

# ...

for host in $RESOURCE_HOSTS; do
```

Or for maximum flexibility you could use a proper Bash array:

```
RESOURCE_HOSTS=(1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2)

# ...

for host in "${RESOURCE_HOSTS[@]}"; do
```

#### Streamlining by eliminating the loop

The current script creates many temporary files in the process,
which is very ugly.
The biggest obstacle to streamlining this into a single nice pipeline is the looping logic.
You could prepare the host values into a JSON list and let `jq` take care of the rest.

Here's one way to create a JSON list from an array of hosts:

```
hosts=(1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2)

values="\"${hosts[0]}\""
for host in "${hosts[@]:1}"; do
    values="$values,\"$host\""
done
```

This assumes that there is at least one host.
It initializes `values` with the first one,
and then appends the others with a comma,
adding double-quotes to make it valid JSON.

With this new variable,
you can chain the `jq` calls like this:

```
cat resource-changes.json | \
jq '.Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.Name=env.RESOURCE_NAME' | \
jq 'del(.Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords[])' | \
jq ".Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords = ([$values] | map({\"Value\":.}))"
```

The `cat` command at the front is a bit ugly, because the filename could be a parameter of the first `jq` call, or replaced with an input redirection.
But that would break the current nice aesthetic flow of the `jq` calls.
This minor issue could be fixed by grouping and input redirection:

```
{
jq '.Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.Name=env.RESOURCE_NAME' | \
jq 'del(.Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords[])' | \
jq ".Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords = ([$values] | map({\"Value\":.}))"
} < resource-changes.json
```

Comment: Thank you. It's really useful! I'll apply the changes you've suggested.